# Como mudar o texto de um "Input.Button" ? Em JS

Tags: javascript

Para alterar o texto de uma div, eu faço :

```
window.document.getElementById("CaixaPrincipal").innerHTML = Mensagem;
```

Agora como faço para alterar o texto de um button? Tentei isso :

```
<input  id = "Botao" type="button" value="Segundo Caminho" onclick = "B()">
window.document.getElementById("Botao").innerHTML = Mensagem;
```

Mas não deu certo :/

Comment: Lembrando que o botão estava assim : 
<input  id = "Botao" type="button" value="Segundo Caminho" onclick = "B()">

Comment: Você não pontua suas perguntas, não tem interação com a galera, confira o [tour do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 3):

Cara o texto do seu `input:button` está no `value` então vc tem que trocar o valor da `value` e não do texto pq teoricamente né texto tem dentro do `input` e sim um valor

Então use `.value` para colocar um valor que vai aparecer como "texto" dentro do botão. E o valor que vc vai declarar tem que estar `entre aspas` se for uma *string* como é o seu caso...

```js
document.getElementById("Botao").value = 'Mensagem';
```

```html
<input  id="Botao" type="button" value="Segundo Caminho" >
<input  id="BotaoX" type="button" value="Segundo Caminho" >
```

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou !

Comment: @AlexJuniorPereira sem problemas amigo! Se a resposta te ajudou e vc considera o problema resolvido lembre-se de marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no ícone ✔️ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da minha resposta. Assim sua pergunta não fica aberta mesmo já tendo sido resolvida.